# Text content in body of the website CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to display text content within CSS body?

```css
body {
  content: 'YES';
  background: lightblue;
}
```

I would like it to be centred as well.

Comment: You're looking for `:after`.

Comment: @SLaks or `:before (or ::before)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content property is reserved for `:before` and `:after` pseudo-element selectors. You can't change the content of an element using CSS. (Unless you hide / place an element over top of it / etc)

So you could do:

```
body:after{
    content: "YES";
    color: lightblue;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

but it won't change the content of `body`.

Answer (score 1):

No.

See [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#content-property)

> The content property dictates what is rendered inside an element or pseudo-element.
>
> For elements, it has only one purpose: specifying that the element renders as normal, or replacing the element with an image (and possibly some associated "alt text").

Since you are targeting an element (and not a pseudo-element), you can't change the text content with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible to display content using CSS. To display `content`, you need pseudoselector, `:before` or `:after`.

To center it you need either flexbox. Demo:

```css
body {
  /* become a flex container */
  /* pseudoselectors are also children so they will be treated as flex-items */
  display: flex;
  /* vertically center flex-items */
  align-items: center;
  /* horizontally center flex-items */
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  /* make body occupy minimum 100% of screen height */
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

body:before {
  content: 'YES';
}
```

Or use absolute positioning for pseudoelement. Demo:

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

body:before {
  content: 'YES';
  position: absolute;
  /* remove this if you don't need vertical centering */
  top: 50%;
  /* remove this if you don't need horizontal centering */
  left: 50%;
  /* replace with translateX(-50%) if you need only horizontal centering */
  /* replace with translateY(-50%) if you need only vertical centering */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```